# how to dismiss a popupwindow when click button?

Tags: android

- ### what i want to do

  i want to write a button that when i click it will show a popupwindow,and when i click the outside or click the button again the popupwindow will dismiss.
- ### what i do

  i use the code like this

  ```
  mPopupWindow=new PopupWindow();
  mPopupWindow.setTouchable(true);
  mPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
  mPopupWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  mPopupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

      brush.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {


              mPopupWindow.setContentView(brushView);
              mPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(v);

      }
  });
  ```
- ### what the problem

  when i click the button again it will show *Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.*

it think it because it tirgger the outside and clicklistener

Comment: tried setting  'setCancelable(true)'  ??

Comment: try using    popupWindow.dismiss();

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below answer:

```
mPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable()); 
mPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

Comment: May be the Button click is not available as the PopupWindow override the Screen behavior so we are not able to handle that click of Btton display inside the Screen.

Answer (score 1):

To make the popup dissapear when clicked on the outside use:

```
   myPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

To open and close the popup on clicking the button, put this code in your `OnClickListener`:

```
    if(myPopupWindow.isShowing()) {
        myPopupWindow.dismiss();
    } else {
        mPopupWindow.setContentView(brushView);
        mPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(v);
    }
```

Comment: (T_T)when i click it will always dismiss

Comment: Edited my answer, try this

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
   myPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

just find a trick
use

```
        mPopupWindow=new PopupWindow(new View(mcontext),WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);
```

i don't know why  but it works